# Using angular filter with string parameter in ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I've a custom angular filter directive which can replace strings using the following syntax:

```
{{ 'MyValue' | replace: 'My':'Foo' }}
```

This works fine. Now I want to use this filter inside a ng-click

```
<button ng-click="alert('{{ 'MyValue' | replace: 'My':'Value'}}')">Click Me!</button>
```

This throws an parse exception (I assume because of the surrounding apostrophes from the alert). What's the correct syntax in this case?

A Plunkr is available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xEGjY40LWORt5nlaJq46

Comment: in your plunkr, the alert is never fired (if i replace the code with normal text). I'm not sure, but it could be because you don't have a controller?

Comment: The problem is this [parse exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=n&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20[%29]&p2=30&p3=alert%28%27{{%20-3%20|%20replace:%20%27-%27:%27n%27}}%27%29&p4=n%27}}%27%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dITHL6DuPstzhxrzg8xV?p=preview)

i added the `controller` and call a function inside controller when `ng-click` fired

```
 <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="x">
   <p>{{ -3 | replace: '-':'n' }}</p>
   <p>
     <button ng-click="x('MyValue','replace','My','Value')">Click Me!</button>
  </p>
 </body>
```

in `script.js`

```
myApp.controller('x', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.x = function(input,filterName,replaceStr,replaceBy) {
      var filtered = $filter(filterName)(input,replaceStr,replaceBy);
      alert(filtered);      
  }
});
```

for the more

`ng-click='alert("1111")'` dose not work because the when u put something inside `ng-click`, `alert()` in this case, it will check for `$scope.alert`  so, alert`is not work inside`ng-click`

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, you cannot use interpolated values as a parameter to an executable attribute in angular ('&').

what you need to do is:

markup:

```
<button ng-click="alert(customValue)">Click Me!</button>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.customValue = $fitler('replace')('MyValue', 'My', 'Value');
```